# AdMob and Firebase exception: unexpected number of IObjectWrapper declared fields: 3

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

While running the app it crashes and goes to some other activity.How to fix it?Attached here the screenshots and code.

[image: error code]

[image: code]

Comment: Please replace the pictures of code and error message with the actual text. Having them as text allows them to be found through search, allows people to copy them to use them for searching or in their answers, and in general is a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you enable Instant Run，and shrink all codes including com.google.android.xxx. Which may cause this crash and I fixed this after disable Instant Run or put com.google.android in a excluding config.